# Back to back MOSFET for RF switching

Tags: mosfet, rf, diodes, pins

I am exploring whether it is possible to reliably switch RF signals with a frequency close to 20 MHz using back-to-back MOSFETs (switching frequency around 200 kHz) with a common source to allow a bidirectional flow of signals when the MOSFETs are ON. I can see that the parasitic capacitances, especially the drain-source capacitance of the MOSFET will increasingly allow RF signals to pass through during the OFF time (gate drive signal is low). I would appreciate suggestions to minimize this potential issue, and I would also appreciate if other potential issues are pointed out. Initially, I was thinking to use PIN diodes to switch the RF signals, however, the PIN diodes that are compatible with the voltage and current rating of my intended application are too slow.

Thanks.

Regards
Allison

Comment: It is unlikely to work as you expect. Pls define specs for your requirements. I/O impedances voltage and slew rate

Comment: Please present the purpose of the RF switch.

Comment: What about the CDS of the Bosfet ?

Comment: The purpose of the switch is to use it as an alternative to PIN diodes. The peak amplitude of the RF voltage will be close to 100 V with a switching frequency close to 20 MHz. Is it possible to introduce an inductor in parallel with the drain-source terminals of the MOSFET to create parallel resonance so that the impact of the output capacitance is minimized at this high RF frequency?